# How to order by field mixed with string and number in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

These are the field (crane_no) values to be sorted

QC11
QC10
QC9

I tried the following query:

```
select * from table order by crane_no DESC
```

but query results does not give in an order because the field is mixed with staring and number (Example:**QC12**). 
I get following results for above query:

QC9
QC11
QC10

I want the results to be in order (QC9, QC10, QC11). Thanks

Comment: Does every entry in the `crane_no` column start with the two letters `QC` ?

Comment: Yes, it starts with two letters QC

Comment: @imsome1 use substring to split the string and convert the 2nd substring to a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to extract the numeric portion of the `crane_no` columns using [SUBSTR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm), cast to an integer, and order descending by this value.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(crane_no, 3) AS INT) DESC
```

Note that I assume in my answer that *every* entry in `crane_no` is prefixed with the fixed width `QC`.  If not, then we would have to do more work to identify the numerical component.

Answer (score 5):

If the data isn't huge, I'd use a regex order by clause:

```
select 
  cran_no 
from your_table
order by 
  regexp_substr(cran_no, '^\D*') nulls first,
  to_number(regexp_substr(cran_no, '\d+'))
```

This looks for the numbers in the string, so rows like 'QCC20', 'DCDS90' are ordered properly; it also takes care of nulls.

Comment: Thanks for this query, it gives the expected result

Answer (score 1):

```
select ...
order by to_number( substr( crane_no,3 )) desc
```